# Смена div через промежуток времени

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function toggle(id) {
  document.getElementById("conten").innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
}
toggle("first");
```

```html
<a href="javascript://" onclick='toggle("first");'><img src="images/ok1.png"></a>
```

Вот такой скрипт есть, меняет div на странице по клику на кнопку.

Как сделать, чтобы он через определенный промежуток времени подменял div?

Comment: Код можно красиво оформить в вопросе, а то так как каша выглядит. Для этого есть специальная функциональность в редакторе (смотрите панель сверху).

Comment: А это так и должно быть "conten" ? Может и не работает потому-что много ошибок в названиях?

Comment: Да, так и должно быть. Чтобы не было путаницы, убрал лишние id - вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/sj9dkdk6/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для задания исполнения через некоторый промежуток времени используйте `setTimeout`

```
function toggle1() { 
   setTimeout(() => {
       document.getElementById("first").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById("second").style.display = "block";
      }, 3000); // 3000 - время в миллисекундах
}
```

Comment: Вместо *setTimeout* используйте *setInterval*, чтобы функция вызывалась каждые 3000 миллисекунд, а не один раз

Comment: @Yernar Sadybekov Так я понял из условия что надо один раз вызвать. Как раз поэтому и написал отдельным ответом, видя уже ваш ответ. Видимо мы по-разному понимаем вопрос ))

Comment: Спасибо! Забыл уточнить, что перед выводом этого div он должен скрывать предыдущий, вот пример - https://jsfiddle.net/sj9dkdk6/4/

Comment: @Alice Khip Скрывать предъидущий тут есть разные варианты, это вы тоже через время хотите или сразу после нажатия? Обновите вопрос, что бы вся функциональность была понятна.

Comment: @Alice Khip, не *setInteval*, a **setInterval**

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин При загрузке страницы через некоторое время (например, 5 секунд) должна происходить подмена одного блока (div id="first") на другой блок (div id="second"), изначально второй блок скрыт с помощью style="display: none". Вот, скрипт должен скрывать второй и показывать первый.

Comment: Поправил с учётом вашего комментария. Незабудьте вызвать функцию toggle1 после загрузки страницы, или повесьте на onLoad

Answer (score 1):

```js
function toggle(id) { 
  document.getElementById("conten").innerHTML =   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML; 
} 
setInteval(toggle("first"), 1000);
```

Этот код будет подменять div каждые 1000 миллисекунд, то есть каждую секунду.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sj9dkdk6/ - почему-то не работает, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: @Alice Khip, Во первых,  id можно присвоить только одному тегу, а вы двум дивам присвоили один и тот же id. Во вторых, не *setInteval*, a **setInterval**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sj9dkdk6/4/ - вот с разными id тоже не получается.

Comment: @Alice Khip, не *setInteval*, a **setInterval**

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! https://jsfiddle.net/sj9dkdk6/6/  - все равно что-то не работает.

Comment: @Alice Khip, https://jsfiddle.net/5wtychfo/

Comment: Не работает же по вашей ссылке, не меняется div ведь.